# Dealing with duplicate requests in IIS that cause unnecessary load

Tags: iis, arr, request

I have an API that has a `CheckStatus` inquiry. Once the client has been given a final status by `CheckStatus` they are supposed to stop polling the API for status updates, but inevitably they dont!

The duplicated requests cause unnecessary load (up to 60% CPU during intense periods)

I'd like to mitigate this by getting IIS to inspect the previous request and subsequent response to see if the result was a "final" status, and if so then just duplicate the previous response without hitting the API.

I suspect this might be possible with Application Request Routing (ARR) starting by inspecting the requested URL using URL Rewite module, but after that I'm a little lost as to where to go.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is you `Status` in the URL or in the headers or POST body. If everything is in the URL URL Rewrite may be an option, but usually you don't put too much logic in there.

Comment: The CheckStatus request parameters are all in the request URL. The response is in the body - hence I may need to use ARR?